# How can I provision a pd-extreme disk in terraform and set the provisions oops to a defined number

Tags: templates, google-cloud-platform, terraform, virtual-machine, terraform-provider-gcp

I am using a GCP managed instance group to provision VMs using Terraform. The module uses an instance template that has the source of an additional non-boot disk set as reference to a created google compute disk. The problem with this is the infrastructure will not deploy because the instance template has a hardcoded disk but I am trying to create a mig instead that creates X number of VM. My primary goal is to set provision iops to extreme-persistent disks and have that create instances from a GCP managed instance group. How can I solve this.

```
resource "google_compute_instance_template" "sample_template" {
  name        = "sample-template"
  description = "This template is used to create sample instances."
  region = us-west6
  project = project_name
  instance_description = "description assigned to instances"
  machine_type         = var.machine-type

  // Create a new boot disk from an image
  disk {
    source_image      = var.image
    auto_delete       = true
    boot              = true
  }

  // Use an existing disk resource
   disk {
    // Instance Templates reference disks by name, not self link
     source      = resource.google_compute_disk.sample_disk.name
     auto_delete = false
     boot        = false
   }
}

resource "google_compute_disk" "sample_dsk" {
    name = "sample-disk"
    type = "pd-extreme"
    zone = "us-west6-c"
    size = 100
    provisioned_iops = 290
}

resource "google_compute_instance_group_manager" "appserver" {
  provider = google-beta
  name     = "appserver-igm"

  base_instance_name = "app"
  zone               = "us-central1-a"

  target_size = 12

  version {
    name              = "appserver"
    instance_template = google_compute_instance_template.sample_test.self_link
  }

  version {
    name              = "appserver-canary"
    instance_template = google_compute_instance_template.sample_test.self_link
    target_size {
      fixed = 9
    }
  }
}
```